# What are all the different accessories that I can get for an NXT?

Tags: nxt

Pretty simple...What are all the different accessories that I can get for an NXT? I know this could turn into a list, but this will be a helpful list, I think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Power

#### 9798 Rechargeable Battery

[image: 9798 Rechargeable Battery]

### Connectivity

#### LEGO 8528 Conversion Cable

Supports connecting sensors and motors from older LEGO® MINDSTORMS® RIS 2.0 (#3804) to new MINDSTORMS NXT Intelligent Brick.

#### LEGO 8529 Connector Cables

Enables connection of sensors and motors to your LEGO® MINDSTORMS® NXT.

#### LEGO 9847 Bluetooth Dongle

Allows remote control of the NXT instead of using cable.

### Sensors

#### MS1048 RF ID Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [Codatex](http://www.codatex.com). Reads 125 kHZ transponders of type EM4102. Various additional transponders are also available.

[image: MS1048 RF ID Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NAA1030 Angle Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Measures axle rotation position and rotation speed.

[image: HiTechnic NAA1030 Angle Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NAC1040 Acceleration / Tilt Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Measures both acceleration and tilt in three axes.

[image: HiTechnic NAC1040 Acceleration / Tilt Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NBR1036 Barometric Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Able to read both atmospheric pressure and temperature. Can be used as part of a weather station or to measure altitude changes.

[image: HiTechnic NBR1036 Barometric Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NCO1038 Colour Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Detects an extended range of more than 15 target colors.

[image: MS1038 Colour Sensor V2]

#### HiTechnic NEO1048 EOPD

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). The EOPD (Electro Optical Proximity Detector) uses an internal light source to detect the presence of a target or determine changes in distance to a target.

[image: HiTechnic NEO1048 EOPD]

#### HiTechnic NGY1044 Gyro Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Accurately measures direction and amount of rotation.

[image: HiTechnic NGY1044 Gyro Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NIL1046 IRLink Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Uses Infrared signals to communicate with trains, Power Functions Motor controller and the Mindstorms RCX.

[image: HiTechnic NIL1046 IRLink Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NIR1032 IRReceiver Sensor

Decodes commands from a Power Functions Remote Control.

[image: HiTechnic NIR1032 IRReceiver Sensor]

#### HiTechnic MS1034 Compass Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Able to measure the earth's magnetic field to determine direction in which it is facing. Has a built-in calibration to help reduce magnetic interference from other sources.

[image: HiTechnic MS1034 Compass Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NMS1035 Magnetic Sensor

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Detects magnetic fields that are present around the front of the sensor in a vertical orientation.

[image: HiTechnic NMS1035 Magnetic Sensor]

#### HiTechnic NSK1042 IRSeeker V2

Manufactured under licence by [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com). Detects infrared signals from sources such as the HiTechnic IRBall soccer ball, infrared remote controls and sunlight.

[image: HiTechnic NSK1042 IRSeeker]

#### LEGO 9846 Ultrasonic Sensor

[image: 9846 Ultrasonic Sensor]

#### LEGO 9845 Sound Sensor

Can measure sound pressure levels up to 90 dB.

[image: 9845 Sound Sensor]

#### LEGO 9844 Light Sensor (**Output:** can also be used for as Lamp)

Can distinguish between light and dark

[image: 9844 Light Sensor]

#### LEGO 9843 Touch Sensor

Detects when it is being pressed by something and when it is released again.

[image: 9843 Touch Sensor]

#### LEGO 9749 Temparature Sensor

Can measure both temparature -20°C to +120°.

#### LEGO 9694 Color Sensor

Acts as a Colour Sensor distinguishing between six colours; as a Light Sensor detecting light intensities, both reflected light and ambient light; and as a Colour Lamp, emitting red, green or blue light.

#### LEGO 9799 Vernier NXT Sensor Adaptor

Allows you to integrate Vernier sensors with the Intelligent NXT brick and the NXT Software.

[image: LEGO 9799 Vernier NXT Sensor Adaptor]

### Motors

#### 9842 Interactiv Servo Motor

Can also be used as a rotation sensor.

[image: 9842 Interactiv Servo Motor]

Comment: This answer is CW: please feel free to extend it as appropriate.

Comment: Added IR Receiver, IR Seeker, Gyroscopic Sensor and notes to clearify that the Servo Motor also is a sensor (rotation).

Comment: 3rd party accessories should be separate.

Comment: The older RCX sensors and motors works just fine with NXT and the PF motors can also be used together with the NXT, either by cable (PF->RCX + RCX->NXT) or by using a IR sensor.

Should we add those as well?